# UIButton not chaging image?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

When I click the `UIButton saveButton` I want the `saveButton` to change its image from `saveIcon` to `doneIcon` for a duration of 1.2 seconds. I've implemented that like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    //create save button
    let saveButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, preview.frame.maxY + space, buttonSize, buttonSize))
    saveButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "saveIcon"), forState: .Normal)
    saveButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "doneIcon"), forState: .Disabled)
    saveButton.center.x = returnButton.center.x
    saveButton.addTarget(self, action: "save:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    saveButton.addTarget(self, action: "canSaveAgain:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(saveButton)
}

func save(sender: UIButton){
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(masterpiece, nil, nil, nil)
    sender.enabled = false
    self.performSelector("canSaveAgain:", withObject: sender, afterDelay: 1.2)
}

func canSaveAgain(sender: UIButton){
    sender.enabled = true
}
```

Although the `saveButton` is being enabled and disabled, the `saveButton` does not change its image even though I set its image to `doneIcon` when disabled (that is: `saveButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "doneIcon"), forState: .Disabled)`).

If anyone could tell me why this happening and how I can change the image of a `UIButton` temporarily I would be quite grateful!

Comment: Comment this line `saveButton.addTarget(self, action: "canSaveAgain:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)` from `viewDidLoad()` and try please.

Comment: Try saveButton.setImage not setBackgroundImage.

Comment: @ChikabuZ Thanks for that! I forgot that there was a setImage function for UIButtons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem! In reality, I had two methods being called when I clicked the `UIButton`. That is, I was calling `save:` *and* `canSaveAgain:` when I pressed the button. As a result, I was simultaneously setting the button to disabled and enabled in an instant.

My edited code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //create save button
    let saveButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, preview.frame.maxY + space, buttonSize, buttonSize))
    saveButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "saveIcon"), forState: .Normal)
    saveButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "doneIcon"), forState: .Disabled)
    saveButton.center.x = returnButton.center.x
    saveButton.addTarget(self, action: "save:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(saveButton)
}

func save(sender: UIButton){
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(masterpiece, nil, nil, nil)
    sender.enabled = false
    self.performSelector("canSaveAgain:", withObject: sender, afterDelay: 1.0)
}

func canSaveAgain(sender: UIButton){
    sender.enabled = true
}
```